# Setting AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All for all controllers

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API project where I want to allow the callers to use all the different query options on all controllers.

Inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874020/query-option-format-is-not-allowed-to-allow-it-set-the-allowedqueryoptions) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860997/where-does-webapi-2-2-odata-v4-enablequery-apply) I added the following code to my WebApiConfig.Register method:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //[already working configuration code]


        //Allow for $format parameter to OData queries
        config.Filters.Add(new EnableQueryAttribute()
        {
            AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All
        });
    }
```

The code compiles and runs, but when I try to add the $format parameter to a query, I get the same exception as previously:

```
Query option 'Format' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.
```

Why doesn't the AllowedQueryOptions setting in WebApiConfig get registered for all controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have both [EnableQuery] attribute and ODataQueryOptions parameter in Controller's method? just use [EnableQuery] attribute, it will apply ODataQueryOption after you return your result and it's allow Format by default.

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/EnableQueryAttribute.cs

if you need ODataQueryOptions parameter, then remove [EnableQuery] attribute, create you own validatasetting, things will work.

Comment: Yes, I have the [EnableQuery] attribute on the actions, and that's been there since the controllers were generated, but it doesn't work.

I don't have ODataQueryOptions in the controller methods.

Comment: Interesting: if I remove [EnableQuery], it works - is there a setting anywhere that would change the defaults for [EnableQuery] to not allow for $format?

Comment: no, you can see it's allowed by default, what's your OData/WebAPI version? https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Query/ODataValidationSettings.cs#L25

Comment: I'm using OData v3